# how to pass arguments to shell script in Jmeter OS sampler generator

Tags: shell, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to pass arguments to shell script in Jmeter - OS sampler processor

My shell script - move.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
source="$1"
dest="$2"
cp $source/*.txt $dest/
```

I run this as

```
sh move.sh t1 t1
```

This will copy data from t1 directory to t2 directory.

Now I want to integrate with JMeter
Below is my setting
[Jmeter image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfEEx.png

Here I am not getting error in execution but files are not getting copied from t1 to t2 directory

Comment: Please give the code example in the text of the question rather than as a screen shot. This makes it easier for others to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. First line of your script is wrong, it needs to look like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```

   See [Bash Shebang](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/) for more details
2. Your [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) configuration is incorrect, you need to use [`-c`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) as the first parameter.

   [image]
3. If JMeter doesn't behave as you expect it to behave first thing you should check is [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). If you don't see anything suspicious - [increase JMeter logging level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to something more verbose.